# How to convert this rows to column in Oracle without aggregation?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hello everyone I have the below table it was designed by a terrible  developer

the table contain the data for the USERS finger prints and their USERID.
the `FINGERID` value from **(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)** the `ISLOCKED` and `ISDUPLICATE` value is `1` or `0` ...each FINGERID  has there image stored in `BLOB`

```
Name        Null     Type          
----------- -------- ------------- 
ROW_ID               NUMBER        
USERID      NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(75) 
TEMPLATE             BLOB          
FINGERID    NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(20) 
ISLOCKED             NUMBER(3)     
ISDUPLICATE          NUMBER(3)
```

I want to display it horizontal way  but no luck since 2 weeks ...below is my desired structure for the select statement

```
Name                    Null     Type          
----------------------- -------- -------------        
USERID                  NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(75) 
FINGERID_1                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_1_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_1_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_1_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_2                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_2_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_2_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_2_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_3                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_3_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_3_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_3_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_4                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_4_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_4_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_4_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_5                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_5_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_5_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_5_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_6                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_6_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_6_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_6_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_7                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_7_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_7_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_7_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_8                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_8_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_8_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_8_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_9                       NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_9_TEMPLATE              BLOB          
FINGERID_9_ISLOCKED              NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_9_ISDUPLICATE           NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_10                      NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_10_TEMPLATE             BLOB          
FINGERID_10_ISLOCKED             NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_10_ISDUPLICATE          NUMBER(3)
FINGERID_11                      NVARCHAR2(20) 
FINGERID_11_TEMPLATE             BLOB          
FINGERID_11_ISLOCKED             NUMBER(3)     
FINGERID_11_ISDUPLICATE          NUMBER(3)
```

I have tried use this code but no luck because I can't show the `TEMPLATE`(`BLOB`),`ISLOCKED`,`ISDUPLICATED`
for each FINGERID because it won't work with `group by`, `pivot` is not a good choice because it require aggregation ...I just want to show the data just how it's but in horizontal way for each USERID .

```
`select 
       USERID,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=1 then 1 END) as FINGERID_1,  
       SUM(case when FINGERID=2 then 2 END) as FINGERID_2,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=3 then 3 END) as FINGERID_3,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=4 then 4 END) as FINGERID_4,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=5 then 5 END) as FINGERID_5,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=6 then 6 END) as FINGERID_6,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=7 then 7 END) as FINGERID_7,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=8 then 8 END) as FINGERID_8,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=9 then 9 END) as FINGERID_9,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=10 then 10 END) as FINGERID_10,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=11 then 11 END) as FINGERID_11,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=12 then 12 END) as FINGERID_12,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=13 then 13 END) as FINGERID_13,
       SUM(case when FINGERID=14 then 14 END) as FINGERID_14
       FROM TBLUSERFINGER group by userid;`
```

Comment: "pivot is not a good choice because it require aggregation" : why not use any aggregation?  isn't your SUM an aggregate?

Comment: I'm forced to use `SUM` in the reality I don't need it because my case statement won't show the result without the `sum`...I just want my data to be horizontally without any editing

Comment: I don't understand something in your output. You will have, for example, columns FINGERID_7_TEMPLATE, FINGERID_7_ISLOCKED and FINGERID_7_ISDUPLICATE, and that is fine. What is the FINGERID_7 column though? The finger id itself is 7, and that is indicated by the column name. I don't think there should be a column FINGERID_7 in the column, but just wanted to make sure. Please advise either way.

Comment: @tbone - because you can't aggregate over a BLOB column.

Comment: @mathguy yes, true.  There are some tricks (hacks) that work for small blobs (converting to hex representations) but my thought is pivot out the non-lobs as needed and do a separate lookup for the blob data (depends on how this table will be used really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those data types do pose a problem.  Instead, you can use `LEFT JOIN` a bunch of times:

```
select u.userid,
       f1.fingerid as fingerid_1,
       f1.template as fingerid_1_template,
       f1.islocked as fingerid_1_islocked,
       f1.isduplicate as fingerid_1_isduplicate,
       . . .
from (select distinct userid from TBLUSERFINGER) u left join
     TBLUSERFINGER f1
     on f1.userid = u.userid and f1.fingerid = 1 left join
     TBLUSERFINGER f2
     on f2.userid = u.userid and f2.fingerid = 2 left join
     . . .
     TBLUSERFINGER f14
     on f14.userid = u.userid and f14.fingerid = 14 ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon I will try and give you feedback =)

Comment: Thanks Gordon  it works after 2 weeks of suffering  :)... it take so much processing time to see 4000,000 rows  result

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.  If your table is very large and joining to itself many times is too slow, you could pivot out everything except for the blob and in its place, store the rowid where the blob can be found.  For example:

```
create table testx (
ROW_ID               NUMBER,        
USERID       NVARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL,
TEMPLATE             BLOB     ,     
FINGERID     NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
ISLOCKED             NUMBER(3)     ,
ISDUPLICATE          NUMBER(3)
);

create unique index testx_uidx on testx(userid, fingerid);

-- insert some test data
insert into testx values (1,'UID1',RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('LOB1')),'1',1,0);
insert into testx values (2,'UID1',RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('LOB2')),'2',1,0);
insert into testx values (3,'UID1',RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('LOB3')),'3',0,0);
insert into testx values (4,'UID2',RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('LOB1')),'1',1,0);
insert into testx values (5,'UID2',RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('LOB2')),'2',1,0);
insert into testx values (6,'UID2',RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('LOB3')),'3',0,0);
commit;

-- pivot out what we can, show rowid to blob data
select * from (
  select userid, rowid as template_rowid, fingerid,islocked,isduplicate
  from testx
)
pivot ( 
  max(template_rowid) rowid_of_template, max(islocked) mislocked, max(isduplicate) misduplicate
  for fingerid in ('1' fid1,'2' fid2,'3' fid3,'4' fid4,'5' fid5,'6' fid6,'7' fid7,'8' fid8,'9' fid9,'10' fid10,'11' fid11,'12' fid12,'13' fid13,'14' fid14)
);
```

Output:

```
USERID,FID1_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID1_MISLOCKED,FID1_MISDUPLICATE,FID2_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID2_MISLOCKED,FID2_MISDUPLICATE,FID3_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID3_MISLOCKED,FID3_MISDUPLICATE,FID4_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID4_MISLOCKED,FID4_MISDUPLICATE,FID5_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID5_MISLOCKED,FID5_MISDUPLICATE,FID6_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID6_MISLOCKED,FID6_MISDUPLICATE,FID7_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID7_MISLOCKED,FID7_MISDUPLICATE,FID8_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID8_MISLOCKED,FID8_MISDUPLICATE,FID9_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID9_MISLOCKED,FID9_MISDUPLICATE,FID10_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID10_MISLOCKED,FID10_MISDUPLICATE,FID11_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID11_MISLOCKED,FID11_MISDUPLICATE,FID12_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID12_MISLOCKED,FID12_MISDUPLICATE,FID13_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID13_MISLOCKED,FID13_MISDUPLICATE,FID14_ROWID_OF_TEMPLATE,FID14_MISLOCKED,FID14_MISDUPLICATE
"UID1","AAzWrKACUAAA1ffAAA",1,0,"AAzWrKACUAAA1ffAAB",1,0,"AAzWrKACUAAA1ffAAC",0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"UID2","AAzWrKACUAAA1ffAAD",1,0,"AAzWrKACUAAA1ffAAE",1,0,"AAzWrKACUAAA1ffAAF",0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

An application could then very quickly do a lookup (to display the blob image for example) using the rowid as needed.